# JS variable not being updated

Tags: javascript, html

I've an issue with calling out JS variable in my HTML. It's simply not getting updated.
The following code is palced in the header:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var sum = 0;
function pushmybutton(id,value){
  sum += value;
  document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
};
</script>
```

There are a couple of questions within the body and they have the following format:

```
<h6>Question1</h6>

<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>

<div class="button1"><a href="#" id="B1A" onclick="pushmybutton('B1A',30);ga('send', 'event', 'Q1', 'Y');">Yes</a></div>

<div class="button1"><a href="#" id="B1B" onclick="pushmybutton('B1B',30);ga('send', 'event', 'Q1', 'N');">No</a></div>
</div>
```

At the end I want to call out the variable sum, I use the following code for that:

```
    <div class="result">
      Your result is:
      <script>
        document.write(sum);
      </script>
    </div>
```

Unfortunately, the variable sum is not being updated and it end up being equal to 0. However, if I use a button at the end with alert(sum) instead, it's being updated.

```
<button onclick=alert(sum);>Results</button>
```

How can I fix it and write the updated variable into my HTML file.

Comment: @jfriend00: I have just migrated the question.  If you know a question doesn't belong on a site, then vote to close instead of posting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `document.write(sum)` happens when the document is initially parsed and displayed BEFORE any of the buttons have been clicked.  Thus all you are displaying at that point is the initial value of the `sum` variable which is, as expected, `0`.

You will need to add code to display the new value of the `sum` variable after you change it.

For example, you could use this:

```
<div class="result">
  Your result is:
  <span id="sumResult">0</span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var sum = 0;
function pushmybutton(id,value){
    sum += value;
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("sumResult").innerHTML = sum;
};
</script>
```